# How to define the vertices for shapes

Tags: box2d

I'm working with box2d on iPhone. I want to define dynamic vertices for shapes when i'm loading it.

Do you have an idea ? I still do not find out best way.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of them for vertex generation / fixture for shape

« [Vertex helper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/779)

« [Physics Editor](http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/features)

[image]

Comment: The physics editor used to define. Because, it generate a plist fine and you could load this file at runtime

Comment: yes I would prepare physics editor pro than vertex helper. Vertex helper works only if number of vertex is 8 or less.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is changing the body appearance and behavior at runtime, you'll have to destroy and create again (each time it changes, might be each frame) the fixture(s) attached to your body, with your new shape(s).

There are a lot of tutorials around the web about it.